# The equivalent of a quasicompact diagonal map and a quasiseparated scheme in Sam Raskin and Arun Debray's "Algebraic Geometry"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I have been reading Sam Raskin and Arun Debray's ["Algebraic Geometry"](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eadebray/lecture_notes/m392c_Raskin_AG_notes.pdf). In Definition 14.6, the author say that a scheme X is quasiseparated if the intersection of two affine opens in $X$ is quasicompact. Following this, he also mention that equivalently the diagonal map $\Delta: X → X \times X$ is a quasicompact morphism. I don't know why this is. By Remark 14.5, this is the same as for all affine schemes $S$ and maps $S \rightarrow X \times X$ , $X \times_{X \times X} S$ is quasicompact. From Definition 14.1, this means that $X \times_{X \times X} S$  has a finite affine open cover. It seems that this is equivalent to a scheme $X$ is quasiseparated i.e. the intersection of two affine opens in $X$ has a finite affine open cover but I can't prove this. How can we prove this? I'm sorry for my lack of ability, but I would be grateful if you could answer.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding, but I still don't get it. If $\Delta: X \to X\times X$, equivalently then $X \times_{X \times X} U$ and $X \times_{X \times X} V$ is quasi-compact. Following this, can we prove $U\times V \subset X\times X$?

Comment: A minor note about authorship: while Arun Debray was the one who transcribed the notes, they were from a course taught by Sam Raskin, and it feels perhaps incomplete to reference the notes just as "Arun Debray's 'Algebraic Geometry'" without discussing the person who gave the course - I'm not completely sure what the correct approach would be here, but please think about it.

Comment: Thank you for your information about authorship. I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the definition of a quasicompact morphism in the linked document is slightly non-standard. However, we can still work with that.

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $U$ and $V$ be open subschemes, then I claim that the following is a pullback square:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U \cap V @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV \\
U\times V @>>> X \times X;
\end{CD}$$

To see this, let $T$ be a scheme and suppose that we have a commutative diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV \\
U\times V @>>> X \times X;
\end{CD}$$

By the commuativity of this diagram, the image of $T \to X$ is contained in $U \cap V$, so it factors uniquely over the inclusion $U \cap V \to X$, which proves the claim.

Now we can apply this to the given definition of quasicompact morphisms: if $X \to X \times X$ is quasicompact, then for affine opens $U$ and $V$ in $X$, $U \times V$ is affine, so $(U\times V) \times_{X\times X}X=U\cap V$ is quasicompact.

For the other direction, it might be helpful to show that the definition of quasicompactness is equivalent to more standard definitions, the usual definition of a quasicompact morphism is that $f:X \to Y$ is quasicompact if the preimage of every quasicompact open is again quasicompact.

Comment: I understand. I deeply appreciate your detailed answer.